# How to override property in spring boot kafka project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

How can i add/override max.poll.interval.ms and max.poll.records in my .yml file in spring boot Kafka micro-service project

What i tried is but it does not work

```
Kafka:
 consumer: 
  max-poll-records: 200
  max-poll-interval-ms: 600000ms
```

Comment: If this is your file then `Kafka` is wrong should be `kafka` and your spacing is wrong. Should be 2 spaces.

Comment: Don't forget your `application.yml` should be at `src/main/resources` and as mentioned, be careful with yaml syntax and format.

Comment: And it's `spring.kafka.consumer...`.

Comment: See also my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Must be like this:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      max-poll-records: 200
      properties:
        max.poll.interval.ms: 600000
```

See Spring Boot docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.kafka.additional-properties

The `max.poll.interval.ms` is not exposed into `KafkaProperties`, therefore its original name from the `ConsumerConfig` has to be used under that `properties` section. Note: you also cannot use `ms` since `Temporal` conversion is only done for exposed properties.